# Scikit - 3D feature array for SVM

Tags: svm, scikit-learn, scikits

I am trying to train an SVM in scikit. I am following the example and tried to adjust it to my 3d feature vectors. 
I tried the example from the page http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html
and it ran through. While bugfixing I came back to the tutorial setup and found this:

```
X = [[0, 0], [1, 1],[2,2]]
y = [0, 1,1]
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

works while

```
X = [[0, 0,0], [1, 1,1],[2,2,2]]
y = [0, 1,1]
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

fails with:
`ValueError: X.shape[1] = 2 should be equal to 3, the number of features at training time`

what is wrong here? It's only one additional dimension...
Thanks,
El

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your latter code works for me:

```
>>> X = [[0,0,0], [1,1,1], [2,2,2]]
>>> y = [0,1,1]
>>> clf = svm.SVC()
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, shrinking=True, tol=0.001,
  verbose=False)
```

That error message seems like it should actually happen when you're calling `.predict()` on an SVM object with `kernel="precomputed"`. Is that the case?

Comment: Unfortunately not, or at least I am not adding such things. Which scikit version do you have running? I have the macport package for mac running here. py27-scikit-learn @0.13.1 (python, science)   Is it too old you reckon?

Comment: 0.13.1 is the version I'm running (and the most recent release). Can you copy the output from running this code in a python session?

Comment: my bet, I found the error. First of all, it was sitting between the chair and the keyboard. The error indeed was from .predict. I forgot to adjust the dimension vector in the predict call and was giving a 3d trained SVM a 2D vector. Sorry, but I guess that happens when one works on his own. :P