# How to use SVM when output label is a 3D array?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

The question is simple, I have a 3D image and I want to segment them using SVM. So I converted the input and output images to 3D numpy array, and now I want to use SVM. But it seems that `clf.fit()` does not support multidimensional label. So how can I train my model where label is multidimensional array?

A simple e.g.:

```
from sklearn import svm
x=[[0,0],[1,1]]
y=[[0,0],[1,1]]
clf=svm.SVC(gamma='scale')
clf.fit(x,y)
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic.py", line 5, in <module>
    clf.fit(x,y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 149, in fit
    accept_large_sparse=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 761, in check_X_y
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 797, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (2, 2)
```

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507165/scikit-3d-feature-array-for-svm

Comment: @ZF007 I  have already seen above link before posting but there the output array is only 1D, and in my case it is 3D.

Comment: If you post some code by editing your question someone  might be able to point you in the right direction. (no expertise on this part of scikit-learn). Your question appears to be valid but triggered triage review likely due to lack of code.

Comment: @ZF007 updated.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding to different y-class labels and that's why its not working. See solution with inline comments below.

```
from sklearn import svm
x=[[0,0],[1,1],[7,8]]
y=[0,1, 2]                 # class labels
clf=svm.SVC()              # clf=svm.SVC(gamma='scale') > gamma is auto. no need to add this.

print (clf.fit(x,y))

q = clf.predict([[2., 2.]])  # simple example to test prediction.

print ('array : %s ' % q)


# use of multiple class labes for y

x=[[0,0],[1,1]]
y=[[0,1],[0,2]]          # the value 2 is to show the difference in printed output.

# add here your `for item in x:` if both arrays are 3D. `for item in y:` needs
# indentation if you do.

for item in y:           # iters through the labeling list.
    print (item)
    clf=svm.SVC()

    print (clf.fit(x,item))

    q = clf.predict([[2., 2.]])

    print ('array : %s ' % q)
```

Printed result:

```
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
array : [1] 
[0, 1]
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
array : [1] 
[0, 2]
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
array : [2]
```

Comment: I need to train the model where input is 3D array and label is also 3D array.

Comment: use the example and modify to fit your own for x-array. Scikit-learn is not fitted to do it how you want it to be done. You can do `for item in x: for item in y:` this allows you to iter through your 3D array (x) and through the 3d y.